# $http.post 400 empty json body at server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this $http.post call?
I get a bad reaquest and the server gets an empty json body.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({

            "Name" : $scope.device.ChildName,
            "Serial" : $scope.device.Serial

        });

        console.log($scope.device.Serial);
        console.log($scope.device.ChildName);
        console.log(data);

        $http.post('http://141.135.5.117:3500/device/register', data, { headers: headers })
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            console.log(headers);




        });
```

This are my headers

```
var headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json;" ,
            "Authorization" : JWT

    };
```

Note: JWT is for Authorization.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**It works!**

Don't know exactly why, but maybe because of this:

I've deleted the Content-type argument in the headers.
And now it works.

I'v read somewhere that http post is standard in JSON format. And you'll overwrite this in the headers and this causes for errors?

Comment: No. by default, angular wires stuff in application/json only unlike jquery . I just saw the problem. there was a syntax error in your headers haha. A semicolon in the end

Answer (score 0):

You're stringifying the object but sending it as application/json. Just send the data without stringifying it and I think the issue will be resolved

Comment: hmmm.. check these: 1. are you using body parser? 2. is there any middlewares which check for the JWT and maybe that's throwing a 400? I'm assuming you're on node..

Comment: Yes Node Js en the headers are fine, the server recieves the header completely but the json data I send arrives at the server as an empty Json body and than gets me the 400 error

Comment: strange.. okay I'm assuming you app.use-ed bodyParser before the route (or included it's .json() as a middleware in the route) because that's what attaches the stuff to the request's body. Also, check if you're recieving the variable names that you're sending. I mean you're sending capitalized variable names here and might be checking for lowerCased ones on the server..

Comment: open up devtools in chrome and goto the network tab and check out if the data that's being sent isn't undefined